# Can I assign 1 GPU per user?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gpu

I'm building a small multi-GPU machine for deep learning that will be shared with my research group. I was wondering what the best way to share access to this is. I know in TensorFlow you can select GPI's with "/gpu:0", etc. But is there a way to only allow each user 1 GPU? (I will only have 3 users and 3 GPUs).

Comment: Just to be clear, does that mean users will be using the machine at the same time?

Comment: Do you want to use GPU cores for computing or have a multiseat linux? If you want the latter take a look at https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat/.

Comment: @grooveplex yes, hopefully they could use it at the same time.